# Creating cms block and calling in phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I just created a cms block from magento admin panel and now I want to get it into the phtml I tried this way:

```
<?php 
$currentview =  Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();

if($currentview = 'default'){
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('ostore_footerb1')->toHtml();
}
else if($currentview = 'it'){ 
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('ostore_footerb1-it')->toHtml();
}
?>
```

I am getting cms block but if statement not working how can I make it working ?

Comment: I take you have 'echo' before the above?   are you sure your editing the correct template file - try putting <h1>HELLO</h1> in there - does that appear?  have you flushed all the caches after making the changes ?

Comment: yes I am sure. Oh I just notice actually I am trying condition using php in the phtml but its not working. how can I use if condition in phtml

Comment: $currentview = 'default'  change to $currentview == 'default'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created CMS block named `ostore_footerb1-it` from admin panel.
Then following will be code to call them in .phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('ostore_footerb1-it')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Another way to do this is :

In the layout (app/design/frontend/your_theme/layout/default.xml):

```
<default>
    <cms_page> <!-- need to be redefined for your needs -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_ostore_footerb1-it" as="cms_newest_product">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>ostore_footerb1-it</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
</default>
```

In your phtml template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ostore_footerb1-it'); ?>
```

Comment: Actually I want to use if statement in phtml which is not working how can i use if statement in phtml ?

Comment: I just edited my question and code is in my question please check

Comment: you are placing single = inside the if statement, it should contain ==

Answer (score 0):

To get static block in `phtml` file

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('ostore_footerb1-it')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Or this:

add this piece to the layout:

```
<default>
    <cms_page> <!-- need to be redefined for your needs -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="ostore_footerb1-it" as="ostore_footerb1-it">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>ostore_footerb1-it</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
</default>
```

and call in phtml

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ostore_footerb1-it'); ?>
```